# what do tags start with ag/ mean in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

When reading code of AOSP, I encounter some tags start with ag/ in some comments. For example, the following one in frameworks/base/core/java/android/window/WindowTokenClient.java:

```
// TODO(ag/9789103): update resource manager logic to track non-activity tokens
```

What do those tags refer to?

Comment: Most likely a ticket reference to track the work that needs to be done in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to access these tickets through public websites, or is it only accessible within Google?

Comment: No, I think these are internal to Google.